# QGIS - Labels on print layout move or don't appear on exported PDF

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, pdf

QGIS 3.16.1 on Windows 10 Pro.  I often manage to get a print layout with label placement just the way I want it, but when I export to PDF, some labels either don't appear or appear in a less desirable location.  Is there some way to control or minimise this effect?

Comment: Did you try changing the resolution when exporting? Can you add a screenshot to be able to see what exactly went wrong?

Comment: Apparently it isn't possible to add images to comments.

Comment: Add it to the question

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me a lot.

I guess the rendering of labeling is trying to place every object at the best place, which is not the same every time, but I can't explain why precisely, so this is my medicine :

1- You can control the appearance of **ALL** your labels in your project doing this :
layer>Vector Properties Dialog >Labels Properties > Setting the automated placement engine
[image]

[image]

Here, you should check : Show unplaced labels, Show all labels for all layers (i.e. including colliding objects), Show candidates (for debugging)

So we are sure about getting all the label.

2.If you want a precised and **fixed** position for each label, good luck using the Layer labeling Options : moving label. [image: Move the label]

With edit mode on, you have to move each label if you want a fixed position.
And then, you should have a precised labeling.
https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html#hard-further-possibilities-with-labeling

Answer (score 1):

I found something that worked for me in QGIS 3.22.

I disabled "features act as obstacles"  and turned all the labels to "high priority."
I also changed the text unit to "map units" somewhere during my troubleshooting. So not sure which switch fixed my problem, or it was a combination of them all.